# Make wireshark packet readable -> JSON/octet-stream

Tags: json, wireshark, packet

I'm trying to read a post request which got captured using wireshark.

Now i was wondering, if there's a way to make the packet content readable, such as requests in fiddler to have readable data?

I would appreciate any kind of suggestions.

The captures packet(Wireshark->Follow TCP Stream):

```
POST /api// HTTP/1.1
X-Unity-Version: 5.2.2f1
GDataVer: v1
Expires: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: xxx
Host: xxx
Content-Length: 576

..>..d....S.y.....#.f..._t~N....j.@..0.....LI.:.%...j......C..F."8.P$...H./f......d.,.y..T.owGv...........yj..|a.....h.d=...M.,8.]'.a}.!....#.....R.O.  -l.....N..xr..T.s.+d.....O:...../..]..|.....bN...y..    1....4e)Q..{g...H....W....F..a..*|].....cvL.U.g..v3.5;.e...,.....2...lUSG........ b.V.a..).) >_-`i7....Z~.B...)............K.|b.M.s3...T[..V.F..8.......z......Y.<.
.q.A.#.[...#z>...A..o.a.2.=.o..M......~j...v,....q.p.M.......?_.    (.I<.....t..).W.;.BKH...w......>n...8=.......U.1..:.2...648........d.....zS.0t...v......R$..#
.].2)..p..3...B...!.....].K..=3........4|.."j$^..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 10:43:48 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.15
Content-Length: 80
Connection: keep-alive

C..........Q.6..3......]c..
8.0.......L.......K...%8...z..Yw........V1.}...L.SI.POST /api// HTTP/1.1
X-Unity-Version: 5.2.2f1
GDataVer: v1
Expires: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: xxx
Host: xxx
Content-Length: 576

..>..d....S.y.....#.f..._t~N....j.@..0.....LI.:..........n;...Fa.7..'.n...i..   .."..h...u....F..H4.0..%p5.:..b.Q........_.o.........k...X.;:`c48.;.J........"n..........[............P...........5U_.F
.|&....
...Z.xs0.......K....U..Ay^.I..&..e
p.1B[....O~..   <.%.Z..T2t..n..hS...U.g.;.?..1..6.$...w...._...\.4.W^).....mG........,)~..Ytw......E    ..'...#%`b;k.O..a.......3c...T....:...
~~$.<{.../..~.V...C%.5...&...%..3.PJ:T...7..c.>.c..~ ,.....LT..-Z<;/.I...\.B
......V..A.\...9<Y?....8#.*.q...[OT%...k.>.......4.. .....:.....L.)..&:........... .,y.(.
..%.,.gl..+`.:..X.,.Q...r..Z..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 10:43:50 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.15
Content-Length: 256
Connection: keep-alive

d4{X.M...A..4.$'.Uj.].N"..-LI.......~A.........^.*
[....z.vN...+k...L.f.S..I'l......I`F..r'..6..
....5..i/].?..:..g"6.uP.^...)e.V.X....&........$$9...r...!....V.C._.f...&....&Vo%.-...7[.S.Q..;.$Fo......m.g.K..c.. ........j.........E.F...Zn.we4.2s..p.VR.V..POST /api// HTTP/1.1
X-Unity-Version: 5.2.2f1
GDataVer: v1
Expires: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: xxx
Host: xxx
Content-Length: 576

..>..d....S.y.....#.f..._t~N....j.@..0.....LI.:.%...j......C..F."8.P$...H./f......d.,.y..T.owGv...........yj..|a.....h.d=...M.,8.]'.a}.!....#.....R.O.  -l.....N..xr..T.s.+d.....O:...../..]..|.....bN...y..    1....4e)Q..{g...H....W....F..a..*|].....cvL.U.g..v3.5;.e...,.....2...lUSG........ b.V.a..).) >_-`i7....Z~.B...)............K.|b.M.s3...T[..V.F..8.......z......Y.<.
.q.A.#.[...#z>...A..o.a.2.=.o..M......~j...v,....q.p.M.......?_.    (.I<.....t..).W.;.BKH...w......>n...8=.......U.1..:.2...648........d.....zS.0t...v......R$..#
.].2)..p..3...B...!.....].K..=3........4|.."j$^..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 10:43:48 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.15
Content-Length: 80
Connection: keep-alive

C..........Q.6..3......]c..
8.0.......L.......K...%8...z..Yw........V1.}...L.SI.POST /api// HTTP/1.1
X-Unity-Version: 5.2.2f1
GDataVer: v1
Expires: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: xxx
Host: xxx
Content-Length: 576

..>..d....S.y.....#.f..._t~N....j.@..0.....LI.:..........n;...Fa.7..'.n...i..   .."..h...u....F..H4.0..%p5.:..b.Q........_.o.........k...X.;:`c48.;.J........"n..........[............P...........5U_.F
.|&....
...Z.xs0.......K....U..Ay^.I..&..e
p.1B[....O~..   <.%.Z..T2t..n..hS...U.g.;.?..1..6.$...w...._...\.4.W^).....mG........,)~..Ytw......E    ..'...#%`b;k.O..a.......3c...T....:...
~~$.<{.../..~.V...C%.5...&...%..3.PJ:T...7..c.>.c..~ ,.....LT..-Z<;/.I...\.B
......V..A.\...9<Y?....8#.*.q...[OT%...k.>.......4.. .....:.....L.)..&:........... .,y.(.
..%.,.gl..+`.:..X.,.Q...r..Z..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 10:43:50 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.15
Content-Length: 256
Connection: keep-alive

d4{X.M...A..4.$'.Uj.].N"..-LI.......~A.........^.*
[....z.vN...+k...L.f.S..I'l......I`F..r'..6..
....5..i/].?..:..g"6.uP.^...)e.V.X....&........$$9...r...!....V.C._.f...&....&Vo%.-...7[.S.Q..;.$Fo......m.g.K..c.. ........j.........E.F...Zn.we4.2s..p.VR.V..
```

Also the Line-based text data can't be read as can be seen in the following screenshot:
[image]

**EDIT:**

Been able to save the files using wireshark (File | Export Objects | HTTP), some files show up normal and can be read. Oters sadly cant be read, they're looking like this:

```
S]þAc—ùÛC:¬òlõ=Y¨–àž½WŒiîø®–Xæ.ÎÐ­dc½d·šGj~÷RSb(ÞvÌè–Q³—¨·wŸ/Ôü:V¸  _×´DÙmœÖÉ%¶¿£ì¹#q23ò[PÇ»äi£Aì³¬Mçòç¬Ta5„¥n
.   Ñ/¬Y w£l*ÿÁ<ÞdBø¯]4q6Ÿšr‘nfDôBá"!.Ø"Nu³ºX°Ìì{·U
,iÃ²èë’
fsì%bÆÁ¼IG›Yfñ  7±Ì÷IP×u})ÛûŠöîd±õßkä²ÅÚÐâ"ç—òŸ•a¢tå‘`Í¸@ðÁýžË<g\ƒáÌÀ€™¶=²Êuf£<…Äß/Y'ÅšÂÅêUµ¡)!±Í‹Dòå&dg“ÂìËÚw"¾ÑgŽpŸtÈ€#\I¤³
0¬ykøµ{x6Ý{§fbì„²~Ì6!íç4“Ðás$òç_4;Fwk4Pþ¼;CG˜œØ³) ¨Ø6a°l¯>«wàþæá¢œà¬Ø];µÅøŒÎÛaø'Žj¢;âO,Ú^½´dÎÁoMNú¢Þ¨éàä‘Æ62ñ™ü¥nœe$"·_ç$²ÓÝ    ÿ Ýi%P§‹“¼“¸Ö£N³ƒ ·°Üqc”¡xdª­CÐë<¨~#PÜcQS”|'}ËóJ–÷(ñžÍ÷+åqš—¯ÅÐaâù.ÖL™@°_ö¾¦ó*Õï¤è‚ ¥8ðòC(y€k6¦tÁŸŒiãM}v9%Üâ’ò\Û\qx©LTa0ÚŽ#Ð>šlºmªÇcdyé(¡ˆÜV*ýôüÇá&3¯ô¹á—dþìÙ.½†d+í;{õ
¯óÔB^]ØÆB ‚ú7Uàµ&Y
‘Ê’‡l,æ,P#†ªrY¨C>¿÷pˆsEÓ%>Q/&…^öc‚hí÷Ð®Ÿ]7é/ë|Àe~#¯‰5÷¥?ýg€ÙþLìoí%¦4³›ünw4P4Æ1â2Iìì"<M÷…EÉÆ‹¤Ö/ØL™•7f/1|;¶h–‹L~$¤¦EDox² ¤¢°˜    ²dÂz`)ì¶å(V¡´¥¼KÅDg~öÇÚîŽîMâhd¾Ô$´Ï•¢HÀI?Ê•Z6ÁÊ=4Ó·®pÝÈ¨³šã2 ê¡ HÕ©bà&2Ë=¥êËì7doøsÿ2ÀŒùmv†Ú7b¢ ÷…õÁ*„Í¿þÇ}¹ÌåXf[±ÂÎAîá=¯ÝÚ°¿)gÇé™ÑèXHÜ7€8úª6Vì(ù%`®jSC€çÕâ*W»@Ý‚h6ƒGRsmå#I:ÚžÕýþu]Ö{ÚÊÌd§‡\š”õ/y#~|†è¸•½†yËy¦A+:ùU .    µ~:<”‚q®¬ÿ
 jl.Â'âCº
§¿$¸××\¬^ÙÐ8ª*r±>‘ÅU(—•ï6ÛóCq^ÚÍ¯øl{ß›«ëîu?µhP×AíþñQìŒA
a!R´CÝŠ°Ó÷YŸšþ–²¢9Ç·ƒÙ/©ÜJ]âµÛ­&Ó©lùÄÏÜÁMpqþg‹Ö=HíXŸ¬ŒL‘L£ªR2…®Ë@ ÎJ{ó‚('ˆl²j¯R`Ø:i=m Šú¢{Ú©Ní´ƒÛ¿X,…Q‡´rZÕ
```

What could cause this? Is there a way to read it properly?

Comment: Shown data indeed doesn't look like plain text, it's more like binary stream. If far-end works fine with it (data isn't a random garbage), then communication doesn't use pure JSON. Perhaps, it's zipped or anyhow else converted into binary to reduce packet size. Or it isn't JSON from the beginnig, there are a lot of binary serialization formats based on JSON.

Comment: BTW, if it's possible to reproduce behavior with small setup (e.g. dumb client sending packet to dumb server, readable by server, but obscure in wireshark), then share the steps to do it, so people here can check details on their PC rather than guessing by data photo.